# How to build an artifact from a given branch in azure pipelines?

Tags: git, azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am super new at this. I want to build an artifact based on a branch in my azure devops repository i.e An artifact from development branch and use that artifact to release to my dev environment in release pipeline. I am using this to only move around code for my databricks workspaces. Any help or direction is appreciated. Thank you

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - development

stages:
- stage: build
  displayName: Build
  variables:
    databricksSourceFolder: $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/$(code_build_path)
  jobs:
  - job: builddb
    displayName: Build Databricks
    steps:
    - publish: $(databricksSourceFolder)
      artifact: Databricks
```

Tried this but this still builds from the main branch and not development

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run build for the **`development`** branch, you need to check with the following things:

1. As you have configured in the YAML file of the build pipeline, ensure the branch filters on the CI trigger include the **`development`** branch.

   ```yaml
   trigger:
     branches:
       include:
       - development
   ```
2. Ensure the YAML file with above configurations is existing in the **`development`** branch.
3. After above steps, when new commits pushed to the **`development`** branch, a new run of the build pipeline will be triggered. This new run will use the new commits on the **`development`** branch to build.
4. If you manually trigger the build pipeline, on the pop-up window, you can select which git ref (branch, tag or commit) the pipeline will run for. Then the new run will use the latest commit on the selected ref to build.

   [image]
5. After the build task (such as [**`DotNetCoreCLI`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/dotnet-core-cli-v2?view=azure-pipelines), [**`VSBuild`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/vsbuild-v1?view=azure-pipelines), etc..), don't forget to use the [**`PublishPipelineArtifact`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/reference/publish-pipeline-artifact-v1?view=azure-pipelines) task to publish the build artifacts so that the subsequent release pipeline can get the artifacts to release.

---

In the classic release pipeline, you can configure like as below:

1. Add the build pipeline as the Source artifact.

   [image]
2. Set the CD trigger (Continuous deployment trigger). If you want the release pipeline can be triggered only when the build runs for the **`development`** branch, you can set the branch filters to only include the **`development`** branch.

   [image]
3. Add the stage to release the artifact to the **`dev`** environment.

   [image]
4. On the **`Pre-deployment conditions`** settings of the stage, you can add the Artifact filters to let the stage be triggered only when the build artifacts are from the specified **`development`** branch.

   [image]

---